# Issue loading ImageView from InputStream obtained from web service in Android 3.0 and above

Tags: android, imageview, inputstream, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

My app has to display an image preview from the image data obtained as InputStream from a web service. InputStream is decoded to Bitmap to display in ImageView. This entire flow is working fine in Android 2.2 and 2.3, whereas it's not functioning with Android 3.0 and 4.0. The bitmap decoded is null in the latter case whereas its fine in 2.x.

Here is the code snippet I use..

```
ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);       
String imageUrl = "my webservice url";      
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet mHttpGetEntity = new HttpGet(imageUrl);
HttpResponse response;
try {
    response = httpClient.execute(mHttpGetEntity);
    XmlPullParser xpp = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance().newPullParser();       
    InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
    xpp.setInput(is, "UTF-8");
    // use xpp for process
    imgView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is));        
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

How can I make this work even with Android 3.0 above. Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code is doing fine on my 4.0. I would say don't worry about 3.0 since it is unstable version no one will use it.

Comment: I tried in a Google Nexus and Galaxy Tab 10.1, both cases, its not working. What could be the issue then?

Comment: do you have internet connection permission? when I first test it in my test app, I get the same thing and then I remember that I need internet permission thingy. I use this image http://ikailansays.files.wordpress.com/2008/12/n506957763_68091.jpg it's not me tho ...

Comment: yes the permission was missing with the sample app I created for posting here! But the issue still exists with my app which involves additional task of parsing the response. updated my code above

Comment: Ok.. I figured out the line causing the issue. Its in the xpp.setInput(is, "UTF-8");
I think the xpp.setInput changes the content of InputStream 'is' which is the cause for my problem. When I commented out that line of code, it works fine.

But i'm not sure how the same original code works fine in Android 2.x!!
Now, how can I load the image from InputStream and also parse it using 
 XmlPullParser?

Comment: what are you talking about? XmlPullParser ? if you look at your question again, you never mention about XML but ImageView and null. if you don't know how to ask the right question, you won't get answer. Also FAQ stackoverflow, one question for one problem, to make the question relevant for other. now that, you have null problem solve, mark this question answered and start a new question for Xml thing.

Comment: sorry for confusions and trouble! Since I wasn't sure what was causing my issue, thought of posting minimalistic code rather than putting everything in which is spread-out across classes in my project. Thanks for the valuable answers!